# JavaScript Date Object in IE9 Allowing Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

When passing an invalid date via the constructor of a JavaScript Date() object IE9 appears to be constructing a valid Date e.g. "56 Aug 2009" returns a date object instance. Chrome by contrast, does not.

Having read the MSDN documentation regarding the Date object in IE9 (link below) and there is a paragraph that states:

> JavaScript is fairly flexible about the date format. It allows for
>   variants such as 8-24-2009, August 24, 2009, and **24 Aug 2009**. For more
>   information, see Formatting Date and Time Strings (JavaScript).

Above paragraph taken from: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532932(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532932%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

The following snippet of code is used to check whether a date is valid. It works in Chrome but not in IE9:

```
function validateDate(d) {
    var dt = new Date(d);
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(dt) !== "[object Date]") return false;

    return !isNaN(dt.getTime());
}
```

When running this code:

```
console.log(new Date("56 Aug 2009"));
```

**IE9 Result**

```
Fri Sep 25 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2009
```

**Chrome Result**

```
Invalid Date
```

Here is a JsFiddle with a more detailed example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WKMdc/8/

This behaviour is unexpected (perhaps due to incorrect assumptions or maybe a bug in the validate that's going unnoticed!).

What alternative method is there to verify a date is valid that would work in IE9 and allow the use of native browser features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also noted in the answer from João, the problem is that when creating a new Date object via the constructor the browser will "help" by performing an addition of days where there is a discrepancy e.g. 29-Feb-2013 is not a valid date (there are only 28 days in Feb in 2013) would become 01-Mar-2013, or + 1 days from the original date.

This is not terribly helpful as in my scenario I would want to flag the 29-Feb-2013 to the user as an invalid entry.

Trying to construct the below date:

```
var parsedDate = new Date("29 Feb 2013");
```

Returns the following Date object per browser:

> **IE9** - Fri Mar 1 00:00:00 UTC 2013
>
> **Safari** - Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
>
> **Chrome** - Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

The same test with a "more incorrect" date:

```
var parsedDate = new Date("32 Aug 2013");
```

Returns the following Date object per browser:

> **IE9** - Tue Sep 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2012
>
> **Safari** - Invalid Date
>
> **Chrome** - Invalid Date

NB IE appears to be more lenient/flexible!

The proposed solution simply checks that the parsed month is the same as the expected month. If not, then one can conclude that a date addition has taken place and a validation message should be thrown:

```
function dateIsValid(dateString) {
            
     var month = dateString.split(" ")[1],
         year =  dateString.split(" ")[2];
            
     var parsedDate = new Date(dateString);
                    
     // create a date object with the day defaulted to 01
     var expectedMonth = new Date("01 " + month + " " + year);
            
     // if the month was changed by the Date constructor we can deduce that the date is invalid!
     if (parsedDate.getMonth() === expectedMonth.getMonth()) {
          return true;
     }
            
     return false;
}
```

Running the below produces consistant results across the browsers:

```
console.log(dateIsValid("01 Aug 2009")); // returns true
console.log(dateIsValid("56 Aug 2009")); // returns false
console.log(dateIsValid("29 Feb 2012")); // returns true
console.log(dateIsValid("29 Feb 2013")); // returns false
```

*Disclaimer:* This is of course, a workaround. But it's simple and works ok for my scenario!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to validate the format of the date and if it is a valid date then create a date object from it.

Comment: True, but I would have to roll my own. Ideally I would like to lean on the native browser implementation(s) to handle this, for example the solution I have at the moment works perfectly in Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting result. It seems that IE9 is parsing `Aug 2009` as `August 1, 2009`, as expected, and then adds the first part of the string (`56`) to this date, i.e.:

`August 1, 2009 + 56 days = September 25, 2009`

It's like saying that the *32th* day of January is February 1. It seems that this was a design decision; if you try to parse other date formats, you'll get the same behaviour:

```
console.log(new Date("08/32/2009")); // August 32, 2009
// LOG: Tue Sep 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2009
```

So, you can either validate your date with a custom regular expression, or live with this *issue* with IE9.

Comment: Yep, very interesting! When you say regex, you mean a regex that would factor in how many days should be in a month, leap years etc or just to assert dd-MMM-yyyy (or whatever the desired format may be)?

Comment: I was thinking in a regex that would validate all possible formats that you are expecting to get. How do you get those date values? Are they introduced by the user?

Comment: In my case the date is already formatted correctly to be dd-MMM-yyyy, but the regex I already have is (too?) simple and wouldn't pick up 29-Feb-2013 as a problem, for example. 29-Feb-2013 of course would not be a valid date! I was hoping to lean on the browser to check this for me as one would in a language like C#  e.g. DateTime.TryParse(value).